# Java 2 Security

Tags: java, websphere, policy

We enabled the java 2 security on the WebSphere 6.1 and we deployed our test.ear along with was.policy which is having the following code.

```
grant codeBase "file:/opt/TEST/EAR/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/system.jar" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/TEST/SYSTEM/config.client.xml", "read, write, execute";
};
```

And then we restarted the Deployment manager, node agent and also the nodemangaer.

But still we are getting the following errors in the IBM logs.

```
0000002b SecurityManag W   SECJ0314W: Current Java 2 Security policy reported a potential violation of Java 2 Security Permission. Please re
fer to InfoCenter for further information.
```

Permission:

```
  /opt/TEST/SYSTEM/config.client.xml : access denied (java.io.FilePermission /opt/TEST/SYSTEM//config.client.xml read)
```

Code:

```
 com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase  in  {file:/opt/TEST/EAR/test.ear/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/system.jar}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /opt/TEST/SYSTEM/config.client.xml read)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:264)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:427)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:213)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:700)
        at com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase.fileNotExists(ControllerBase.java:286)
        at com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase.readConfigFromSystemProperty(ControllerBase.java:267)
        at com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase.createConfigStream(ControllerBase.java:227)
        at com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase.readConfigFile(ControllerBase.java:556)
        at com.test.system.server.common.base.ControllerBase.init(ControllerBase.java:374)
        at com.test.system.client.servlet.FrontController.init(FrontController.java:96)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:340)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:435)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:524)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Please help us in rectifying the problem.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ( unless you are deploying an exploded ear file )

```
grant codeBase "jar:file:/opt/TEST/EAR/test.ear!/test.war/WEB-INF/lib/system.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission; 
};
```

The key bits are the "jar:" at the front of the codeBase location, and the exclamation mark ( "!" ) after the ".ear"

I've taken out the explicit FilePermission- if you are granting AllPermission, there's no need to grant explict FilePermissions as well. ( But if you are granting AllPermission, why are you bothering switching Java 2 security on in the first place ? )

Comment: WAS always runs with an exploded EAR file.  Using the jar: syntax isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path in was.policy.  The following snippet works for me:

```
grant codeBase "file:test.war" {  
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

See the InfoCenter topic [Configuring the was.policy file for Java 2 security](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_waspolicyfile.html) for more information.

Note: I agree with DaveHowes that enabling Java 2 security but granting AllPermission is worthless.